# How can remove the circle of ApplicationBarIconButton in windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone-8, application-bar

I create the Application Bar with 4 icon Buttons and 3 normal menus. It's working fine.

But i don't want, the circle around the icon button. How can i remove that.

And another one question is how to see the icon button text in normally. That means i click the more icon that time icon button visible. But i want no using more button and want to see the icon button text. It's Possible.

Please Help Me.Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cannot remove the circle, neither you can "expand" the application bar so you can see the labels of each button. It is simply against the Windows Phone UI.

But as it is .NET, you can easily create your own buttons bar at the bottom of your page. Of course, it might be difficult to implement the UI logic for you menu items so they behave like the native application bar does (you could consider using the build-in application bar for you menu items and set its mode to "Minimized").

But: why would you do all this? In my opinion, apps should follow all UI guidelines and should all look the same (especially when compared to native apps) ;-)

Greetings